# Model has 2 foreign keys. Cant insert foreign key into the table of an other table. mysql database. ruby on rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having problems with my rails application. I have 3 tables( skill, version, and skillversion). skillversion has 2 foreign key columns from skill and version) I have a form for skillversion and every time I add a skill associated with version, It should add a skill and use version from drop down list(gets list from version table).

Issue: When I submit a form. it is adding a new version row in the version table with different id. I dont want it to add a different row if similar version exists. After submitting the skillversion table, It should get the id of existing version and add it to version_id column in skillversion. Please help and let me know if you need any more information. I am attaching relevant code from project.

RIGHT NOW: it doesnt add any value into skillversion table

model/skill.rb

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :skillversions
end
```

model/skilversion.rb

```
class Skillversion < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :skill
belongs_to :version
end
```

model/version.rb

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :skillversions
end
```

controllers/skillversions_controller.rb

```
    def create
    @version = Version.find(:number)
    @skill = Skill.new(params[:skill].permit(:name))

    if @skill.save
        @skillversion = Skillversion.new(params[:skillversion].permit(:version_id, :isActive))
        @skillversion.skill = @skill
        @skillversion.version = @version
        if @skillversion.save
            redirect_to skillversions_index_path
        else
            render json: @skillversion.errors, status: :internal_server_error
        end 
    end
        render json: @skill.errors, status: :internal_server_error
end
```

views/skillversions/_form.html.erb

```
<%= fields_for :skill do |s| %>
<%= fields_for :version do |v| %>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="dform">
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= s.label :name, 'Skill Name', :class => "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= s.text_field :name, :class => "controls" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= v.label :number, 'Version', :class => "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls" >
      <%= v.collection_select :number, Version.find(:all), :id, :number,  :class => "dropdownwidth" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox" >
        <%= sv.check_box :isActive, :class => "controls " %>
        <%= sv.label :isActive, 'Active?', :class => "checkbox" %>
      </label>
      <%= sv.submit 'create it!', :class => "metro" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following, but it seems like it would be easier to make a version via a [after_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) call back if it is just for versioning?

Comment: So, you mean.. after saving the skillversion(without the version_id).. I should save the version_id in the skillversion table?